# Getting a subscript out of range error on list object

Tags: vba, excel

So, I've been working on a code that allows editing of database tables via excel, and I've run into a snag with a table object.

The code is written almost the exact same way on other worksheets, but for some reason, only this worksheet gives me the **subscript out of range error when setting the list object**. I've check the name of the table and tried changing it a couple of times. What am I missing?

Here's the code so far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim CustomersConn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim CustomersCmd As ADODB.Command
    Dim lo As Excel.ListObject
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lrs As Range
    Dim lr As Excel.ListRow
    Dim Customers As Variant
    Dim areaCount As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Rows As Range
    Dim rRow As Range
    Dim lRows As Excel.ListRows
    Dim Counter As Double

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(11)
    Set lo = ws.ListObjects("TProspects")
    Set CustomersConn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set CustomersCmd = New ADODB.Command
    Set lrs = Target

    For Each Rows In lrs.Rows
        On Error GoTo jmp

        '========Section 1===========
        If Counter < 1 Then
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("ID").Range).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(lo.ListColumns("ID").Range) + 1
        End If
        '^^^^^^^^Section 1^^^^^^^^^^^

        Set lr = lo.ListRows(Rows.Row - 5)


        CustomersConn.ConnectionString = SQLConStr
        CustomersConn.Open
        CustomersCmd.ActiveConnection = CustomersConn

        CustomersCmd.CommandText = _
            GetUpdateText( _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("ID").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Prospect").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Contact").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Email").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Phone").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Address").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("City").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("State").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Zip").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Buying Group").Range).Value, _
            Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("Type").Range).Value)

        CustomersCmd.Execute

    Next Rows

    CustomersConn.Close

    Set CustomersConn = Nothing
    Set lo = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Set lr = Nothing

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

jmp:
End Sub
```

**GetUpdateText** function:

```
Function GetUpdateText(ID As Double, Prospect As String, Contact As String, Email As String, Phone As String, Address As String, City As String, State As String, Zip As Double, Corp As String, CType As String) As String

    Dim SQLStr As String

    SQLStr = _
        "UPDATE Prospect" & _
        " SET Type = '" & CType & "'," & _
        "Prospect = '" & Replace(Prospect, "'", "''") & "'," & _
        "Contact = '" & Contact & "'," & _
        "Email = '" & Email & "'," & _
        "Phone = '" & Phone & "'," & _
        "Address = '" & Address & "'," & _
        "City = '" & City & "'," & _
        "State = '" & State & "'," & _
        "Zip = " & Zip & "," & _
        "[Buying Group] = '" & Corp & "'" & _
        "WHERE ID = " & ID & _
        "IF @@ROWCOUNT=0" & _
        "INSERT INTO Prospect (" & _
        "Type,Contact,Prospect,Email,Phone,Address,City,State,Zip,[Buying Group])" & _
        "VALUES (" & _
        "'" & CType & "'," & _
        "'" & Contact & "'," & _
        "'" & Replace(Prospect, "'", "''") & "'," & _
        "'" & Email & "'," & _
        "'" & Phone & "'," & _
        "'" & Address & "'," & _
        "'" & City & "'," & _
        "'" & State & "'," & "'" & Zip & "'," & "'" & Corp & "')"

    GetUpdateText = SQLStr

End Function
```

Comment: without looking into the actual data of the code it's quite difficult, but the error "subscript out of range error when setting the list object" has almost always to do with iterating through an array, with either:
1. you are trying to iterate through an array that has nothing in it, or ...
2. you are going beyond the indexable range of the array.
in the case of you code be sure to check your "For Each Rows In lrs.Rows" , "Set lr = lo.ListRows(Rows.Row - 5)" and "Intersect(lr.Range, lo.ListColumns("ID").Range).Value = WorksheetFunction.Max(lo.ListColumns("ID").Range) + 1" check these lines.

Comment: Are you sure you have a worksheet of index 11?

Comment: In addition to what Matt says, are you sure that your table is definitely on sheet index 11?

Comment: Also, don't use `Rows` as a variable name, because its an internal collection object and very confusing for anyone to debug. e.g. `Rows = Range.Rows`. eurgh

Comment: Error suggests that the `ListObject` isn't named `"TProspects"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matt Cremeens and Andrew Wynn brought up a valid point which directed me to where I needed to be.

While I did indeed have the table on sheet index 11, for what ever reason, utilizing the name of the sheet instead of the index value worked. I totally forgot that Worksheets is an associative array. As far as why the index did not work, it's a total mystery.